# How to color some parts of the image programmatically?

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have an Italian map, and I need to color some regions programmatically.

This is the image:

[image]

As you can see there are few regions with a different color (orange).

I have a page where I need to highlight the areas of user, so I need to color those areas differently. The base is grey and the selected must be orange.

Now, How could I do it programmatically?

I would like to avoid creating one image for each user.

Any Ideas?

Comment: PHP has a spattering of imaging libraries, pick one.

Comment: @GrantThomas COuld you be more specific? Do you mean libraries as GD? The problem is, how cand I color the areas (read: how could I calculate the areas where i need a different color)

Comment: Guys stop just pasting links to color-related functions, it's not that easy to achieve, he could use the imagefilltoborders, despite the result would be ugly due to the antialiased borders, the problem is, how will he detect which region to color? and the coordinates? he would need all the shapes coordinates referenced to a region at least. Also this would really spend a lot more resources than having the images prepared (for example 1 grey and 1 orange) and use a front-end approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered jQuery powered interactive maps like this one:

[Link 1](http://css.flepstudio.org/css-menu/css-mappa-italia-8.html)

Alternatively, if you get really stuck you could look at something like this (paid plugin!)

[Link 2](http://winstonwolf.pl/clickable-maps/italia.html)

Answer (score 1):

I still prefer creating "one image per user". It's actually not per user. Make your variations of the image already created, and load them by your server-side logic. I mean, something like sprites. Have every part both colorized and non-colorized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think php's GD or imagick libraries are so powerful, and if so, it won't be that easy to do, and the resulting image could lose quite a lot of quality, as the borders of the map are even antialiased.

I would suggest you to Google for "interactive maps", normally you have the vectorized images and use Javascript and CSS to achieve what you are trying to do. Maybe there are already something for Italy.